# Running multiple versions of a servlet web application parallel

Tags: java, servlets, version, osgi

I want to run multiple versions (like myapp2.1, myapp2.2 ...) of several Java Servlet based web applications parallel.

One possibility could be to deploy each version to a separate servlet context (which should have its own class loader?!). But I think it will be hard to manage and won't be flexible, since an application is a quite large block. What if an application should contain a service in two different versions? Maybe that is not a good idea ...

The environment will be GlassFish >= 3.0.

What is a better way to run multiple versions of a servlet application parallel? Could OSGI help?

Answer (score 4):

Each web application will be loaded using its own ClassLoader (at least any container I know of; I can't imagine why a container would not do this). So, it should just work. Different versions of your classes will not interfere with one another.

Make sure you do not include any of your classes in the container's own ClassLoader -- for example by putting a .jar in lib/ in Tomcat's directory (not sure of the equivalent for Glassfish). That would be shared by all web applications, and would override whatever is in the web app.

Comment: +1. To reiterate: web applications already work like this. They are completely separated from each other (as far as classloading is concerned). You can deploy to different versions of the same WAR with two different names.

Comment: What you want to watch out for are shared resources like databases. You probably need to separate them as well, or maybe have all versions access the same database, but then you could get into cross-version-compatibility problems.

Answer (score 2):

> One possibility could be to deploy each version to a separate servlet context (which should have its own class loader?!).

J2EE applications use separate hierarchy of ClassLoaders and are isolated from each others. Quoting [Classloaders and J2EE](http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE.htm):

> #### J2EE classloader hierarchy
>
> J2EE specifies that a hierarchy of
>   classloaders is needed to achieve the
>   isolation between applications, but
>   leaves it to the vendors to define the
>   exact structure. However to comply
>   with the J2EE specification, most
>   vendors have classloaders for each of
>   the J2EE application components
>   depending on its location. Further,
>   these classloaders have a hierarchy
>   among themselves, i.e. they have a
>   parent-child relationship. Figure 21.5
>   shows a sample hierarchy of
>   classloaders. Note that each
>   application server’s classloader
>   hierarchy might slightly differ.
>   Application server vendors sometimes
>   tend to treat two or more of these
>   classloaders as one. For instance, a
>   certain application server might treat
>   Application classloader and EJB
>   classloader to be the same. But the
>   general concepts behind the hierarchy
>   remain the same.
>
> [Sample Classloader Hierarchy in J2EE Application Servers http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE_files/image016.jpg](http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch21-ClassLoaders_and_J2EE_files/image016.jpg)
>
> **<sub>Figure 21.5 Sample Classloader Hierarchy in J2EE Application Servers.</sub>**

So, yes, each webapp would have its own `ClassLoader` (thanks god).

> But I think it will be hard to manage and won't be flexible.

Why hard to manage? Why not flexible? How many instances are you going to run in parallel? Actually, what problem are you trying to solve? You may get better answer if you describe the real problem. So, can you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly configure it to be so, all servlets are multi-threaded and can be invoked several times at once.

So, do you want several web applications with the same code but different names or several servlets inside the same web applciation with different configurations?  Please edit your question with a scenario.

---

EDIT:  You have now edited the question.

You can simply just name the war file you deploy like application20091230, application20091231, application20100101 and let Glassfish assign it to the corresponding URL.  If date is not granular enough, then either a datetime or a buildnumber.

That's what we do for having several versions in a single internal test server.

Comment: My question is not related to multi threading. It is about different configurations and versions of the application.